# How to purchase Windows for Boot Camp?

Tags: windows, bootcamp

1. This is a clean install. New Mac. No previous versions of Windows has been purchased or installed.
2. I need an ISO, not a DVD because there is no optical drive on the new Macs
3. Microsoft only sells Windows 8 Update, not the full thing. There is a "system builder" edition out available through some "partners" and apparently it also only comes on DVD.
4. Windows 7 it seems can be bought from Microsoft but only in certain regions (mine is not included) and only in DVD form.
5. I see you can get ISOs of Windows 7 from [Digital River](http://www.mydigitallife.info/official-windows-7-sp1-iso-from-digital-river/) but that only works if you have a product key, ie. you have already purchased Windows (currently no way to do this, see points 1-4).

Really Microsoft? This is why people run to Pirate Bay. Any solutions welcome :)

Comment: Yes, Microsoft makes it overly complicated... but Windows 8 (full version) is available from http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832416550&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-, see this: http://superuser.com/questions/493608/is-it-possible-to-buy-windows-8-online-as-a-digital-download . I hope you can purchase it from your region.

Comment: @jaume You should make that an answer.

Comment: @zigg It may not be as useful as I first thought, I checked shipping destinations and according to newegg's FAQ at http://www.newegg.com/Info/FAQAboutShopping.aspx?FAQType=5 : `We do not offer international shipping options at this time`. Let's see if this is a problem for the OP, otherwise I'll be glad to make it an answer.

Comment: So there is no way you can turn a disk into ISO by another computer?

Comment: See comment on the answer. I know how to rip a normal DVD into an ISO on another machine but I don't know if there's any dodgey DRM stuff on the Win 7/8 DVD that makes the rip fail or if the installer from these DVDs check for a physical disc through some DRM system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Windows 8 has been released in your country, you should be able to find a reseller with the System Builder version available as a DVD. Local system builders is a pretty big business in most countries so just look around for someone offering custom built Windows systems.  A quick Google search on "create a DVD ISO on OS X" shows lots of how-to articles for that step.

You can either use an external DVD reader (maybe $30) or get somebody with a DVD to create the ISO for you.

Comment: Definitely had hoped to go digital only but this will have to suffice :) Simply ripping the DVD to ISO will work in the case of both Windows 7 and 8? ie. there isn't some dodgey DRM thing on the physical discs that the installer checks for?